# Building custom Linux kernel in yocto build system

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am using BSP layer meta-ti in yocto build system with poky as distro. When i set the MACHINE variable as "beaglebone", the PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel is "linux-ti-staging" i.e the kernel source will be downloaded from SRC_URI present in recipe linux-ti-staging-version.bb.

I have written my own kernel recipe(my-custom-kernel-version.bb) where i have specified the SRC_URI pointing to different github path to defconfig for the custom kernel source. This recipe is present in meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/

I do want to do any kernel modification in yocto using bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel.

How can i make bitbake  to pickup up my-custom-kernel-version.bb
rather than the linux-ti-staging-version.bb to fetch the kernel source.

Comment: Yes there is a way to build a custom linux kernel. Try to do bitbake menuconfig if you want customisation of current linux kernel. Your question is not precise on what is your issue...

Comment: @void_brain, I have updated the question putting the actual requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your distribution file. You can simply add:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "my-custom-kernel-version"
```

Make sure that you have `PROVIDES += "virtual/kernel"` in your kernel recipe.